# Firebase database onCreate don't update all records

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm new to cloud functions and I have a big blocker which I can't understand. I created `onCreate` handler and it triggers correctly on every new item. If I put multiple items to the database and my callback is invoked many times sometimes `snap.ref.update` is not updating item.

Here is my code:

```
...
.onCreate(async snap => {
    const item = snap.val()

    const newImageUrl = await asyncFunctionThatMovesImage(item.url1)
    const newImageUrl2 = await asyncFunctionThatMovesImage(item.url2)

    return snap.ref.update({
       img1: newImageUrl,
       img2: newImageUrl2
    })
})
```

At this point 50-75% of items are actually updated but other.. i dont know why, but they have old data. Each function returns 200 (I checked in the logs).

Is there any limit on Firebase Storage or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not clear what product is triggering the function (`...` is not helpful), nor what the actual problem is (what are the `asyncFunctionThatMovesImage` calls? Does the problem still happen if you remove those calls?). Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). since having a complete standalone snippet of code that reproduces the problem is the best way to improve the chances someone sees what's going wrong for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is that your function updates the same ref that it is listening to, so if there are no img1 or img2 children on the location, this will trigger the function itself again.